# Stokes Theorem Question

Tags: calculus, stokes-theorem

Use Stoke’s theorem to evaluate 
$$ \int_C F dr = \iint \operatorname{curl} F dS = \iint (-Pg_x-Qg_y+R) dA $$

where $F =\langle 2z, 4x, 5y \rangle$ and $C$ is the intersection of
$z = x + 4$ with the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 4$.

I calculated the $\operatorname{curl} F = \langle 5i+2j+4k\rangle$

$dS$: The projection of the surface onto a plane, in this case, because $z=g(x,y)$, it's onto the xy plane.

$$ z = g(x,y) = x+4 $$

$$g_x = 1$$

$$g_y = 0$$

$$ \iint (-1) dA $$

Switching to polar

$$ \iint (-1) rdrd \theta $$

where $$0≤\theta≤2\pi$$

$$0≤r≤2$$

I calculated the integral and got an answer of $-4\pi$. I haven't completed many Stokes' Theorem problems though so I'm not sure if my process, or answer, are correct.

Comment: I didn't normalize the norm in my answer and found it has the same answer as yours when I normalized it. I delete my post.